# Is $f(x)=x^{4}-2x^2 +3$ Eiseinstein in 2-adic $\mathbb{Q}_{2}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

I think it is because $|1|_{2}=1$,

$|2|_{2}=2^{-1}\leq 1$ and

$|3|$,where 3 is prime

I am using the following Eisenstein criterion for $f(x)=a_{n}x^{n}+...+a_{0}$: $|a_{n}|=1$, $|a_{0}|=prime$ and $|a_{i}|<1$. On page 129 in http://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/ANT.pdf

As you can read from the comments, we have not agree if f is Eisenstein.

The **original** problem asks to prove $\mathbb{Q}_{2}[\sqrt{1+\sqrt{-2}}]$ is totally ramified. My approach was to show f is Eisenstein and then use the theorem below.

In the same page we have the following theorem: $K[\alpha]$ is totally ramified iff the minimal polynomial f of $\alpha$ over K is Eisenstein.

So $\mathbb{Q}_{2}[\sqrt{1+\sqrt{-2}}]$ minimal polynomial should be Eisenstein. Can you tell me what is going on?

Comment: Are you taking $p=2$? Then why do you say $|3|=2^{-1}$?

Comment: Yes, it is for p=2. I fixed it

Comment: that too. I added $|3|=1$

Comment: does it all look good?

Comment: Then Eisenstein doesn't apply, does it, since $|3|=1$. What statement of Eisenstein are you using?

Comment: You're right. I am bit puzzled. I am asked to show $\mathbb{Q}_{p}[\sqrt{1+\sqrt{-2}}]$ is completely ramified, where $\sqrt{1+\sqrt{-2}}$ is a root.

Comment: The theorem: For discrete valuation . Eisenstein and extension $\mathbb{Q}_{p}[\alpha]$  iff $\mathbb{Q}_{p}[\alpha]$  is comp. ramif.

Comment: I don't understand what you have written, and I'm not sure what definition you are using for "Eisenstein".

Comment: The usual Eisenstein polynomial

Comment: You are not making this easy. Please write out a detailed, complete (as in full sentences) definition of Eisenstein and a statement of the theorem that you are purporting to use.

Comment: okay I will add it in the post

Comment: I added both of them.

Comment: I said it in the comments. I will add it above.

Comment: You do realize that $3$ is not a prime in the $2$-adics?

Comment: how do i check whether is prime or not? I guessed that because $\mathbb{Q}_{2}$ contains the rationals.

Comment: But anyways my main question is how can it not be Eisenstein given the theorem I stated.

Comment: You have misstated the theorem. The theorem says $L/K$ is totally ramified if there exists $\alpha$ such that $L=K(\alpha)$ and the polynomial for $\alpha$ is Eisenstein. It doesn't say, "for **every** $\alpha$". Find another $\alpha$ that generates the same extension, but has the property that its polynomial is Eisenstein. Then write it up and post it as a solution.

Comment: I need to show $\mathbb{Q}_{2}[\sqrt{1+\sqrt{-2}}]$ is tottaly ramified.

Comment: You need to find another $\alpha$ that generates the extension, but has the property that its minimal polynomial is Eisenstein.

Comment: Making any progress toward finding another $\alpha$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your polynomial $f(x)=x^4-2x^2+3$ is amenable to Eisenstein because $f(x+1)=x^4+4x^3+4x^2+ 2$, and this is an Eisenstein polynomial.